# Como envìo el token JWT en cada solicitud HTTP mediante el Request interceptor de axios?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, axios

Tengo el proyecto en vue, el login funciona, me devuelve el token si las credenciales son correctas y me lo almacena en el local storage, mi duda es que debo poner en el interceptador de axios para que el envie el token en cada solicitud y me deje entrar a rutas protegidas??[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//este es mi axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../store'
import router from '../router'

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_URL

// Request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    const token = store.getters['auth/getToken']
    if (token) request.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`

    const locale = store.getters['lang/locale']
    if (locale) request.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = locale

    // request.headers['X-Socket-Id'] = Echo.socketId()
    return request
})

// Response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
    const { status } = error.response

    if (status >= 500) console.error(error)

    if (status === 401){
        store.dispatch('auth/removeAllData')
        router.push({ name: 'login' })
    }

    return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

Comment: No se ve. El código va como texto, no como imagen

Comment: ya bro, espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: ¿Estas usando esa instancia de axios para hacer las llamadas a la API? No tendrías que exportarlo para usarlo en algún componente o donde sea que quieras usarlo?

Comment: .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                this.$router.push({name: 'admin'});
                });
tuve que poner esto en cada peticion axios, lo que quiero es hacerlo de manera global

Comment: Que tiene que ver eso con enviar un token en el header?